# Oracle json_object selects weird unicode symbols instead of text

Tags: sql, json, oracle

```
SELECT email, json_object( 'email' IS email)
FROM users
```

result is

```
qq@mailinator.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
{"email":"\u0000q\u0000q\u0000@\u0000m\u0000a\u0000i\u0000l\u0000i\u0000n\u0000a\u0000t\u0000o\u0000r\u0000.\u0000c\u0000o\u0000m"}
```

If I use `to_char(email)`, then result is OK. Is this an Oracle bug?

Comment: Escaped unicode characters are perfectly valid in JSON. I'm guessing that your `email` column is NVARCHAR2, and rather than figure out whether each character is part of the ASCII codepage, Oracle just escapes every character.

Comment: I don't follow the logic, All my columns are varchar2 and DB char set is Unicode. But imo there is no difference between `select * ` and `SELECT email, json_object(..` so this is a bug if this doesn't have a proper solution

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue because my database column is `clob` and i converted the string from `WE8MSWIN1252` to `UTF8`.

I could replace `chr(0)` (the visible escaped unicode: `\u0000`) from my column and it worked:

```sql
select   json_object(
            key 'key' value replace(convert(tab.clob_col, 'UTF8', 'WE8MSWIN1252'), chr(0), '')
) json
from     my_table tab;
```

before: `"key": "\u0000t\u0000e\u0000s\u0000t",`

after:  `"key": "test",`